# Google Maps V3 API reserve geocode - Unknown property <latlng>

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

On my map I have some Markers. Onclick I want to get the markers address using reserve geocoding.

Here is my function:

```
...
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_obj[ii], 'click', function(){   
        show_marker_information(this);                             
    });  

...

    function show_marker_information(obj){                                        
        //obj = marker                                                            
        if(typeof(infowindow) != 'undefined')                                     
            infowindow.close();                                                   

        var latlng_search = obj.getPosition();                                    

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();                                
        geocoder.geocode({                                                        
                'latlng':   latlng_search                                         
            },                                                                    
            function(results, status){                                            
                alert(results.toSource());
            }                                                                     
        );
```

When clicking on a marker firebug tells me:

```
Unknown property <latlng>
[Break On This Error] J.toSpan=function(){return new P(this....n(d){return d==k&&c||d instanceof a}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my error:

```
 geocoder.geocode({                                                        
            'latlng':   latlng_search                                         
        },                                                                    
        function(results, status){                                            
            alert(results.toSource());
        }                                                                     
    );
```

there is no 'latlng' property at geocoder. it has to be 'location' instead of 'latlng'.

Comment: That definitely works. However, did you try 'latLng' as camelback instead of lowercase? I think that would normally be the preferred solution.